# How to have a form refresh a different form

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

So I have 4 forms that make reports, dates, location, costs, and materials. All of these forms can open a 5th form, projects, where you select which project/s you want the reports on, close, and then customize the reports in whatever of the first 4 forms you have open. You may also then go to a different of the first 4 and do another report on the same projects you selected.

My task is to put a warning that projects are selected and how many. I did this by making a flag table and a warning label, and upon loading one of the initial 4 forms it'll check the flag table and make the warning visible or not. The issue is that whatever form I used to get to projects is still open when I close projects, so the warning label won't appear until the form is refreshed/reloaded. How can I make the projects form detect which form is open and refresh it when I close projects?

Comment: A simple, but less efficient solution might be to use a timer (2-sec) to refresh/requery the warning label.  How many users do you have? If only a few, that approach could work, if you have hundreds, it would cause horrible performance.

Comment: Hundreds, and people already complain that it's slow, so this is a no go unfortunately.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `AllForms` collection or better still `Forms` ?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if each form is loaded. Create a line for each form you need to check.

`If CurrentProject.AllForms("formname").IsLoaded Then Forms!formname.Refresh`

Alternatively, when 5th form is opened, pass a value to it identifying which form called it. Can use OpenForm command OpenArgs argument to pass form name then use the OpenArgs property of 5th form to refresh calling form.

`Forms(Me.OpenArgs).Refresh`

Comment: The refresh did nothing, but I was able to use the load function with Forms!CostForm.LoadForm and your if statement works perfectly.

Comment: Maybe should be Requery instead of Refresh.